# .htaccess on apache2 on mac ventura struggles with rewrite

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, ventura

I've got a htaccess with the following:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ display.php?username=$1
```

If given

```
'http://localhost/example/blue'
```

then on the webpage must show the username 'blue' using php code however mac fails and instead it says

```
404 not found.
```

The server runs on

```
/usr/local/var/www/example
```

directory and not the

```
'/Library/...'
```

directory.

I've enabled

```
mod_rewrite,
```

i've changed to

```
AllowOverride All.
```

I installed and set up

```
php 8.3.0
```

Comment: Does `http://localhost/display.php?username=blue` work from your browser?

Comment: @anubhava you mean http://localhost/example/display.php?username=blue ? Yes, it works

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: @anubhava when i do that the web browser shows 'Internal Server Error...' and the error_log shows invalid command

Comment: ok add this line in .htaccess `Redirect /abc /example/display.php?username=blue` amd then see what happens when you visit `http://localhost/example/abc`

Comment: @anubhava i get url not found. I've just downloaded xampp and it works on it but i was hoping to get it fixed on mac...

Comment: I run Apache on my Mac using brew

Comment: @anubhava im din't think i'm using brew for apache cause that runs on the 'library' path. i'll keep trying and i'll try compare xampp settings with apache2

Comment: Please clarify your setup. _"The server runs on `/usr/local/var/www/example`"_ - is that supposed to mean the document root for localhost is set to that? Seems rather unlikely, because then why would `example` still be in the URL path? (You'd have to have another folder named `example` _in_ `example` then.)

Comment: @CBroe. On mac if use homebrew usually the apache2 website root folders are in the '/Library/Webserver/Documents/ folder - also meaning that the setup is different. If you use the pre-installed apache2 server, if im not mistaken then apache2 uses the same structure as linux /usr/local/var/www/example. I suspect that the configuration is different coz xampp also uses mysql php apache2

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, whether you have `localhost` pointing to `/usr/local/var/www/`, or `/usr/local/var/www/example`. I would assume it is the former, so that `http://localhost/example/` points to the latter then. In which of those two is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: Lol, @Cbroe I'm using the pre-installed apache2 that runs in the '/usr/local/var/www/' the .htaccess file is the root directory of 'example'

Comment: So does `http://localhost/example/display.php?username=blue` show the desired content, or is that also getting a 404?

Comment: @CBroe, it's returning a 404 error. But that's not the only issue. I f tweak the httpd.conf file like for instance, 'AllowOveride All' then apache fails to run, the browser says contact your adminstrator.

Comment: _"then apache fails to run, the browser says contact your adminstrator"_ - not sure how the browser could say anything, if you don't have a web server running for it to make a request to in the first place ... but either way, go check what the Apache error log has to say. Any maybe do a config test, https://serverfault.com/a/232146